# ¿Como puedo llevar a cabo esta consulta?

Tags: php, sql, array

Tengo el siguiente dilema, supongamos una base de datos de personas, hay 3 columnas (**dni**, nombre, características). La columna de características será un array que guardará varios datos. Ej:

```
"11111111A","Rodolfo",["pelo azul","ojos marrones", "tatuaje en hombro"]
"22222222B","Agustín",["pelo verde","ojos marrones"]
"33333333C","Sagrario",["pelo rosa","ojos azules", "tatuaje en biceps"]
```

Quiero hacer la siguiente consulta: Devuélveme el nombre de todas las personas que tengan "ojos marrones".

Tendría que recorrer todas las filas de esa columna, y recorrer todo el array de esa fila? Algún otro método?

Decir que las características deben ser infinitas, se pueden agregar nuevas características a una persona.

Comment: Voy a utilizar MySQL, nunca me ha dado problemas, pero no se como plantear la consulta.

Comment: Puede haber estado mal diseñado ese módulo, porque ahi se ve claramente una relación de muchos  a muchos y esta super claro, si es MSSQL al menos la columna debió haber sido XML para poder hacer una consulta parametrizada.

Comment: Puedes modificar la estructura de la base de datos? Si el campo características guardará n cantidad de ellas, la normalización indica que deberías crear otra tabla para guardar esos datos.

Comment: Aún puedo modificar la base de datos si, es lo primero que de diseña antes de crear la aplicación. Lo de guardar los datos de caracteristicas en otra tabla puede ser una solución, pero es limitada. Si creo una tabla con 20 columnas, solo podria agregar 20 caracteristicas, necesito que sea infinito.

Comment: La otra tabla sería algo como idCaracterística, fkPersona, Característica, así podrías guardar n cantidad de características.

Comment: No me valdría, no puedo crear un millón de características

Comment: ¿Porque no puedes crearlas?

Comment: No entiendo el comentario, Fabian... creas tu tabla así como te dije, y podrías agregar la cantidad de filas que sean necesarias para todas las características de cada persona...

Comment: Ah! Tal vez no tienes claro el concepto de relación 1:N, por eso piensas que no podrás almacenar el millón de características, pero es precisamente para eso que existe esa relación! En la tabla persona tendrás a cada persona 1 vez, y en la tabla características tendrás N cantidad de registros, 1 registro por característica... Ojalá me haya explicado.

Comment: Te refieres algo asi como "11111111A","ojos azules" - "11111111A","tatuaje"

Comment: Si la tabla la haces como puse de ejemplo, tendrías una tupla del tipo (1, 1, 'ojos azules'). El primer número indica el identificador en la tabla Características, el segundo es la clave foránea que apunta a la Persona, y la tercera es la característica.

Comment: Deberias leer sobre normalizacion de datos, y sobre todo tercera forma normal. No vas a agregar una columna por caracteristica, debes agregar una fila por caracteristica en otra tabla.

Comment: Leyendo tus comentarios parece ser que piensas que *normalizar*  separando los datos en tablas es complicar, cuando es justo lo contrario. Yo incluso haría 4 tablas, sí 4 tablas: `persona, parte_cuerpo, caracteristica, persona_caracteristica` en esas tablas **cada dato estaría una sola vez**, no miles o millones de veces. Las relaciones serían expresadas en la tabla `persona_caracteristica` una fila por cada característica y cada persona. Así, cualquier dato es posible: cuántas  y cuáles características tiene una persona, cuantas personas tienen un tatuaje en el hombro derecho ...

Comment: ... cuantas personas tienen un solo ojo, cuantas personas tienen los ojos negros, cuántas personas tienen un ojo verde y otro marrón ¿? , cual es el porcentaje de calvos, cuantas mujeres tienen el pelo corto, etc, etc, etc. ¿Por qué se puede hacer todo eso? Porque tienes las tablas debidamente **normalizadas**. Quizá digas que ahora nada de eso se requiere. Ok, pero los requerimientos pueden cambiar en el futuro y si no normalizas, cualquier evolución lo que hará será bloquear tu sistema y si hay millones de registros te quiero ver. Además está el rendimiento, el mantenimiento y mucho más...

Answer (score 0):

prueba lo siguiente. suponiendo que la variable $con es tu variable de conexión en donde defines tu servidos usuario contraseña y db.

```
$sql="SELECT caracteristicas FROM nombredelatabla;";

$resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


WHILE($datos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

foreach ($datos.caracteristicas as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}}
```